# Is there any easiest way to make changes CSS & JS, and show changes without setup:static-content:deploy & without disabling static content generation?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

Can anyone suggest the easiest way to make changes CSS & JS without

**setup:static-content:deploy**

every time.

And without disabling static content generation.

Comment: which mode you are using ?

Comment: Developer Mode. But sometimes it's too slow.

Comment: if you are using developer mode, no need to deploy content each time.only need to flush cache!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
open you theme path in 'pub\static\frontend'

eg : pub\static\frontend\Porto\furniture\en_US\local.css
```

find your css file and change it , also apply same changes in your original file.

```
no need to apply every time command.
```